# A simple way to implement multiple use jquery functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This is quite a complicated one but I'll try and explain it as best as I can.

I am developing a wordpress site that utilises quite a few jQuery plugins (plupload, jCrop etc).

On some pages there are multiple instances of plupload and some of these instances require the user to be able to crop an image.

To save me writing the same code out multiple times I just use the same jQuery but with variables appended by a php variable.

I created a class that 'writes' the required jQuery into the dom and then it can pass in a variable to be used to append the jQuery variables to make them unique.

I then just instantiate multiple objects of that class at different parts on the web page as and when I need that functionality.

For instance (example simplified for clarity)...

On a web page..

```
<div>
<?php
  $thisUploader = new reqJqueryClass("firstUploader");
  $thisUploader->implementMainUploadPicture;
?>
</div>

<div>
<?php
  $anotherUploader = new reqJqueryClass("secondUploader"); 
  $anotherUploader->implementSecondaryUploadPicture; // This also has crop functionality
?>
</div>
```

And then the Class takes the parameter passed to it (firstUploader / secondUploader in this case) and writes it to $this->dynamicPartOfVar.

Inside the class I have...

```
public function implementMainUploadPicture() {
  $this->start_Javascript();
  $this->set_Up_Object_Specfic_Vars();
  $this->run_Plupload_jQuery();
  $this->end_Javascript();
}

public function implementSecondaryUploadPicture() {
  $this->start_Javascript();
  $this->set_Up_Object_Specfic_Vars();
  $this->run_Jcrop_jQuery();
  $this->run_Plupload_jQuery();
  $this->end_Javascript();
}
```

etc .. etc.. (this is actually more functionality included other than just an upload and crop library)

Then I have methods that simply look like this...

```
protected function start_Javascript() {
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
<?php
}

protected function end_Javascript() {
?>
  });
  </script>
<?php
}

protected function set_Up_Object_Specfic_Vars() {
?>
  var dynamicPartOfVar = "<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>"; 
// $this->dynamicPartOfVar is firstUploader or secondUploader (or whatever was passed in)
  var imageManipulationObject = ();
<?php
}

public function run_Jcrop_jQuery() {
?>
  imageManipulationObject["myVariable"+dynamicPartOfVar];

  // rest of vars set up the same way
  // so that I can have multiple instances of this jquery
  // on the same page without conflict ....
<?
}

public function run_Plupload_jQuery() {
?>
  imageManipulationObject["anotherVar"+dynamicPartOfVar];

  // rest of vars set up the same way
  // so that I can have multiple instances of this jquery
  // on the same page without conflict ....
<?
}
```

Even though this is a bit of a code smell it seems to work a treat. My only concern is whether this system will be scalable (I need quite a few upload/jcrop etc objects on one page) or whether it will bog the browser down doing it this way?

I thought that once the site is tested and working then I would copy all the jQuery from the browser, paste it into it's own file, minify it and then just call it via the header (or footer) as normal?

However, I wondered if there was a "correct" way of achieving the same thing that I'm trying to do here?

I'm self-taught in everything that I'm doing so rarely implement the 'best practice' and I don't know of any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks for any help you can give me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code is really hard to maintain.

First of all, if you're using multiple jQuery versions, then you should use `jQuery.noConflict()`:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Second of all, I didn't understand the following code:

```
protected function start_Javascript() {
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
<?php
}
```

Why not load the code in "header.php" or "index.php" or any other view file ?!
This function doesn't work, because it doesn't `return` anything or `echo` anything.

Third of all, if you really want to mix Javascript and PHP together, then you should do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_arr = new Array();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        <?php
        $arr = array('test1', 'test2');
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++){
        ?>
        js_arr.push('<?php echo $arr[$i]; ?>');
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

It will fill the PHP array in the JS array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure why my question was voted down? I'm not using different versions of jquery - you may have misread that. However, to answer your point, the <code>start_Javascript</code> writes the javascript to the DOM so that it appears if you were to 'view source'. It all works fine. It's just that I get the sense there is a much better way of doing it. I can't load the code in the header because I don't want to write the same jquery code out over and over. This way I have several jquery jigsaw pieces and I just call the pieces I need to get the funcitonality I need.

Comment: The jQuery plugins shouldn't cause any problem. You can initiate 2 jQuery objects that way: `$(".jcrop_image_1").jCrop();` and $(".jcrop_image_2").jCrop();`. The code you wrote doesn't make sense and it's really hard to maintain. On another hand, the PHP functions you wrote don't `return` or `echo` any type of value. They are useless. It's really bad to mix JS and PHP the way you did.

Comment: Yep, I know you can initiate 2 plugins that way but the problem comes if you want to have the plugins working together (sharing variables) sometimes and not others. And also if you want to use different variables within the scope of the function etc.. It *is* really complicated to explain and maybe it's too complex for this kind of medium... :-( thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You can avoid using a bunch of variables and store the data in the HTML5 `data` attribute. Mixing JS and PHP that way won't solve your issue and it'll make it harder to debug and to maintain.